# Как «поставить на паузу» процесс чужой программы?

Tags: java, android

Мне нужен метод, который бы остановил программу на некоторый срок («заморозил»), подобно методу `Thread.sleep()` — только у чужой программы.

Я разрабатываю программу, которая модифицирует некоторые данные чужой программы во время её выполнения.
Мой код работает хорошо, но есть одна проблема:

Делать это нужно за 3-5 секунд (иначе чужая программа выполнится с наполовину модифицированными данными и выдаст ошибку), а мой код выполняется примерно 20 секунд.

Да, я пытался ускорить, но это не слишком помогло. Я подумал, что, возможно, в Android есть какой-нибудь метод для остановки и возобновления через неопределённое время процесса чужой программы.

Я начал гуглить и наткнулся на метод `Process.sendSignal(Process.SIGNAL_KILL);`, с помощью которого можно «убить» процесс, но это мне не подходит.

Comment: Это невозможно.

Comment: Из-за чего вызвано данное ограничение?

Comment: Теории параллельных вычислений, принципов работы виртуальных машин и механизмов безопасности операционных систем.

Comment: Существует ли какое-либо альтернативное решение? Замедление или что-то ещё (подобное видел в GameGuardian)?

Comment: Зависит от того, что именно вы делаете и зачем.

Comment: Модификация некоторых данных(Я уже написал)

Comment: С таким уровнем осведомлённости могут повторить только свой первый комментарий.

Comment: Есть один такой компилятор на андроид, но в нем нельзя изменять код нормально(только через интерфейс) и чтобы изменить и нужно данные модифицировать.

Comment: Но моя логика выполняется дольше начала компиляции

Comment: Из-за этого ошибки